# Can I run a line of javascript in a JQueryTemplate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I want to run a bit of javascript, but I can't figure out the syntax:

My template looks like this:

```
 {{if (results.length > 0)}}
        $('#commentHeader').hide();
 {{/if}}
```

I tried this:

```
 {{if (results.length > 0)}}
       ${ $('#commentHeader').hide(); }
    {{/if}}
```

no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
 {{if (results.length > 0)}}
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#commentHeader').hide();
     });
   </script>
 {{/if}}
```

this will execute the function if the page is ready.

Comment: Gave it a try but I think the <script> tags are interfering as I think the template is also defined in a <script>

Comment: can you post the complete file? This is the way it should work, just work your way around the PHP (using echo perhaps?).

Comment: actually have solved it now, I put the script outside the template and made a function to do the hiding, then I simply did `${function();}` to call it :)